# Is it possible to format strings in C like Python's f-strings?

Tags: c, f-string

In Python it's possible to format strings conveniently using f-strings:

```py
num = 12
print(f"num is {num}") # prints "num is 12"
```

Is it possible to do something like this in C? Or something that is similar to that?
Currently, to add variables to the output I am using this method:

```c
int num = 12;
printf("num is %d", num);
```

Is this the only way to add variables to a print statment in C?

Comment: You could use `sprintf` to "print into a string" and then output that new string, but `printf` seems to be the way to do formatted output in C

Comment: C doesn't have literal string interpolation, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it may be possible (and maybe some crazy scientist has done it already) to use macro magic plus `_Generic` to do something like: `magic_print("15 + 3 = ", 15 + 3, "\n");`

Comment: Forget Python and use C. Why everybody wants such "tricks" and thinks it is important for programming.

Comment: @i486 because `import this` and `Beautiful is better than ugly!` you silly

Comment: @YuDaChi Beautiful is `%d` format. If you think it is very hard, use other language.

Comment: @i486 you have an professional deformity, your sense of beauty is broken

Comment: @YuDaChi Become a painter if you think only for beauty.

Comment: @i486 i'm already CG/3D artist and game developer(tech artist) and i bring light to your temple of darkness, no matter what you want.

Comment: @YuDaChi OK, you are artist but far away from programmer.

Comment: @i486 i'm also a data scientist, you silly 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> {num}")
> ```
>
> Is it possible to do something like this in C?

No, it is not possible. C language is a programming language without [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming). It is not possible to find a variable by its name stored in a string in C.

Python on the other hand is an interpreted language with a whole interpreter implementation behind it that keeps track of all variable names and values and allows to query it within the interpreted language itself. So in python using a string `"num"` you can find a variable with that name and query its value.

PS. It is *possible* with many macros and C11 `_Generic` feature to omit having to specify `%d` `printf` format specifier and get C more to C++-ish `std::cout <<` function overloading - for that, you may want to explore [my try at it with YIO library](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio/#beginner-examples-heart_eyes). However, for that, it would be advisable to just move to C++ or Rust or other more feature-full programming language.

Answer (score 0):

As ForceBru said you can use `sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...)`, but you need to have an alocated string to receive that result:

```
int num =0;
char output_string[50];
sprintf(output_string,"num is %d", num);
```

now `output_string` can be printed as you want

Comment: I'd suggest using `snprintf()` over `sprintf()`, and of course detecting and handling any errors.